# How can I test logged-in functionality in Rails 5 using Minitest and Omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest, omniauth-google-oauth2

I'm writing tests for a Rail 5 app and I'm struggling to test signed-in functionality. I'm using Minitest and Omniauth (specifically Google OAuth).

Most of my methods check for `current_user` and redirect to root_path if it's not present. I need to write tests that simulate that `current_user`, preferably specifying the id.

If I do something like this:

```
test "should load settings for logged in user" do
  current_user = {id:1}
  get settings_path
  assert_response :success
end
```

The test fails with a redirect to my root_path. I've tried to dig into this and it looks like current_user isn't set when the controller checks.

Apologies if I'm missing something fundamental, but could someone please explain how I can test logged-in functionality?

Comment: `current_user = {id:1}` just sets a local variable in the block. How exactly to do this depends on how the authentication system is implemented. You could stub the `current_user` method or do a post request to your login method. Devise/Warden have built in testing methods.

Comment: The `current_user` method is part of ApplicationController, I'm not having much luck attempting to stub that.

Comment: you cannot access current_user in test cases. You can sign in with user having id 1. Like this sign_in User.find(1). if you already have users data in test enviornment

Comment: https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing

Comment: Thanks folks. I struggled to follow the integration test instructions on their GitHub wiki but figured out I need to do:

1. `get "/auth/google_oauth2"`

2. `OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google_oauth2] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({ ... })`

3.  `get "/auth/google_oauth2/callback"`